# Go Keyboard plugin documentation

Tags: android, keyboard

Is there somewhere a documentation on how to write a plugin for Go Keyboard (or any other one)?

If I write a plugin for Go, it will also work for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, GO doesnt have extension/API for other developers. 
but I may be wrong, you can find more information here : http://golauncher.goforandroid.com

Or may be you checkout other open soft-keyboard like : https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard

<strike>GO keyboard is not working on iPhone, thus your plugin will also not work.</strike>

Comment: As far as I can see there's a Go Keyboard for iPhone too: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/go-keyboard-customize-keyboard/id916226412?mt=8

Comment: @AdrianBer ahh, just know they have.

Comment: I saw that you can install plugins, themes and languages from Play Store. The link that you posted does not have any documentation (nor I couldn't find any on that website).